# How do I advertise a game about writing role play?

Tags: mmo, rpg, online

I head & develop a very niche game called "Verdict", which you can read about [here.](https://main.verdict.dev) Basically, Verdict is a writing game. It has the mechanical elements of an RPG and the multiplayer elements of an MMO, but you can only gain experience by writing roleplay with other players.

It's pretty similar to MUDs/MUSHes, if you're familiar with those.

I've been wracking my head on how to advertise this, though. Advertising to MUDs is an option, but they're very old and not very popular- there are newer RP venues like GTA V RP or Neverwinter Nights, but I'm not familiar enough with the scenes to know how to "break in", if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to figure out your target audience.

Is it freeform roleplayers / collaborative writers who are looking for a more gamified medium of expression? Or is it MMORPG players who are looking for a more roleplay-centric game?

The decision which one you choose would influence both *where* you present your product and *how* you present it.

In each case you would present it as "what you already know, but in the way you want it". When you target the freeform roleplayers, you would present it as a new platform for roleplaying, but with gamification features. When you target MMORPG gamers, then you would present it as a new MMORPG, but with a much larger focus on roleplay.

Comment: Once you've identified your core target as Philipp says, go out and talk to some of them. Find out what communities and sites they frequent — that will give you a good idea of where to advertise to reach other people with similar interests, as well as how you can tailor your game features and the way you communicate them to catch their attention.